# while showing low quality video preview, taking high quality photo

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm using AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 when showing video preview. And i want to take photo with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto (Full quality).When pressed take photo button removing AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and adding AVCaptureStillImageOutput.

```
    [session removeOutput:captureOutputVideo];
    [session addOutput:captureOutputPhoto];
```

Problem is, taked photo is being dark. If take photo after wait 0.4 sec, photo is better.

```
    usleep(400000);
```

How can i do it without wait?

Comment: Hi,ervanux,have you get it out? I have the same problem now.